# How long does object exist after exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, garbage-collection

Hello:  lacking some basic understanding about garbage collection.  Is it valid to call method in the object after exception is thrown by the same object? (in the code example below, please see the comment).

Consider example below:  premise here is that object does calculation on some data, and needs to inform the caller that it encountered some bad data, however, it still needs to report all the calculations it has done previous to encountering bad piece of data.  The code in the example below works, but I suspect that it is only working because GC didn't get to destroying the `class1` object yet.

If it's invalid, what would correct design look like for the same use case?

Any help is appreciated.

Caller:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
try
{
    class1.Calc(arrayOfValues);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    LogError(e.Message);    
}
Draw(class1.GetPoints()); //is it valid to make GetPoints() call here??
```

Class:

```
public class Class1()
{
    private List<string> calculatedPoints = new List<string>(); 
    
    public void Calc(string[] values)   
    {
        foreach(string p in values)
        {
            if(!isValid(p))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("invalid value encountered");
            }
            calculatedPoints.Add(DoSomeCalculation(p));
        }
    }
    public List<string> GetPoints()
    {
        return calculatedPoints;
    }
}
```

Comment: since you hold a reference to class1, the gc will not attempt to release it.

Comment: Also in this case, the validation errors don't seem that exceptional.  Consider using a result object that contains success/fail flag, data, and associated errors, rather than relying on exceptions for control flow.

Comment: Another issue with your code: you should do validation *before* mutating the list, otherwise you will get partial results if an exception happens in the middle. An immutable class might make even more sense

Comment: The result of `class1.GetPoints()` might be inconsistent because the `Calc` method stopped in the middle of the loop, but this is entirely independent of garbage collection. How did you develop the idea that exceptions caused garbage collection of still reachable objects?